# Why does JSX parse empty spaces as children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I just realized that I can pass empty strings as children in react.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Comp> {} {} </Comp>
  );
}
```

Here is the result directly copy pasted from `React Developer Tools`.

```
{
  "children": [
    " ",
    " ",
    " "
  ]
}
```

I found a [Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12270) describing this. The issue is closed because that is an expected behavior.

My question is, what is the use case for something like that? Why is this an intended behavior?

Comment: its due to the  `{ }` being rendered as a blank space. so `<div>{ } X { "string" }</div.`  would be `<div> X string</div>`

Comment: I guess it's not clear to me why you *wouldn't* expect this behavior.  Whitespace is text, and text constitutes a child node.

Comment: Initially I encountered this while learning NextJS. I tried to use <Link> component. And I used it like <Link> {//something} </Link>. Link component expects single child and I got a runtime error. Then tested the same in bare react and saw that in developer tools. Probably that's how I confused. Of course you are right @David, text constitutes a child node. Feel free to post an answer about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whitespace is text.  Text is a node.  That's really all there is to it.

And the code has three separate whitespace nodes:

```
<Comp> {} {} </Comp>
      ^--^--^--- here
```

How much whitespace is there doesn't make a difference, or what other text is there doesn't make a difference.  All that matters in this case is that there are three distinct elements of text (separated by curly braces, which are coincidentally empty but still exists and delineate the text for the parser).